# Crear filtro grayscala para imagen con CSS

Tags: css, css3, filtros-css

¿Como puedo aplicar un filtro de grayscala a una imagen con CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sintaxis

```
.imagen {
  filter: <filter-function> [<filter-function>]* | none
}
```

Un ejemplo aplicando un filtro a una imagen sería:

HTML

```
<img class="blur" src="imagen.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%)
  filter: grayscale(20%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta original de [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612047/3613462)
[Webkit cuenta con soporte para filtros CSS](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit) Compatiblidad cross-browser!

```css
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

/* Disable grayscale on hover */
img:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/630/170/">
```